# Issues inserting JWT token into Ansible Playbook

Tags: ansible, yaml, jwt

I am attempting to include a JWT token in my Ansible playbook for accessing an API endpoint. Here's the playbook:

```
---
 - name: Request ex API
   hosts: localhost
   connection: local
   tasks:
      - name: Get Ports
        uri:
            method: GET
            url: "https://sandboxapi.domain.com/ex/v3/port/userport"
            return_content: yes
        headers:
            Accept: application/json
            Authorization: "JWT {{token.json.token}}"
        register: response
      - debug:
            msg: "{{ response.content }}"
```

However, I obtained this error message:

```
lw@APMBC02D20RHMD6R playbooks % ansible-playbook ex.yml
ERROR! conflicting action statements: uri, headers
```

The error appears to be in '/Users/lw/Ansible-EX/playbooks/ex.yml': line 6, column 9, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

```
   tasks:
      - name: Get Ports
        ^ here
```

I am unsure about about how I can include the JWT token into the playbook. Can anyone help by providing guidance on how I can include the JWT token into the playbook?

Answer (score 1):

Let's have a look at that error message:

> ERROR! conflicting action statements: uri, headers

We can see the `uri` and `headers` that it says are conflicting as keys of the task definition here:

```yaml
   tasks:
      - name: Get Ports
        uri:
            ...
        headers:
            ...
```

Ansible is seeing both of these as separate actions on the same task, and doesn't know what to do with that. Instead, what you need to do is pass `headers` as an option to [the `uri` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.3/uri_module.html).

In the wonderful world of YAML, that means changing some whitespace:

```yaml
   tasks:
      - name: Get Ports
        uri:
            method: GET
            url: "https://sandboxapi.domain.com/ex/v3/port/userport"
            return_content: yes
            headers:
                Accept: application/json
                Authorization: "JWT {{token.json.token}}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Your indenting is incorrect. Try:

```yaml
---
- name: Request ex API
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  tasks:
    - name: Get Ports
      uri:
        method: GET
        url: "https://sandboxapi.domain.com/ex/v3/port/userport"
        return_content: yes
        headers:
          Accept: application/json
          Authorization: "JWT {{ token.json.token }}"
        register: response

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ response.content }}"
```

Comment: Thanks @Kevin C - the indentation fixed it. BTW, how do I have a variable to handle the JWT token from POSTMAN?